# Google AnnotationChart with only points

Tags: charts, google-visualization, time-series, timeserieschart

Has anyone ever figured out how (if possible) to remove the connecting lines on a [Google AnnotationChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart)?
My goal is to create a scatter plot where the x-axis is time data and the y-axis displays annotated values.
I could use a [ScatterChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart) (or even perhaps a [BubbleChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart)), but the killer-feature of AnnotationChart is the time-aware x-axis and the zoom/scale/scroll feature along that time axis.

I tried hacking around this by turning the option `colors` to white (the background color), but that also turns all points/annotations to white.

Similarly, there's a line `thickness` option, but the default (`0`) is already set and has non-zero thickness.
Other values for `thickness` I tried: `null`, `undefined`, `-1`... none had any effect.

Any ideas?